# I want to place my my nav - Top - Right - Bottom - Left

Tags: css

I want to place my nav in 4 different places. Top, Right, Bottom, And middle. But I cant seem to get it to work. And when i for example mean Right, it should still be in the center of top and bottom. I donät know if you understand but i don't really know how to describe it better.

```css
#navOne {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#navTwo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 43vh;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#navThree {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 86vh;
}

#navFour {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float: left;
  margin-top: 42vh;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p id="navOne" class="navs"><a href="about.html">About me</a></p>
<p id="navTwo" class="navs"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></p>
<p id="navThree" class="navs"><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></p>
<p id="navFour" class="navs"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></p>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into a fiddle and it seems to look like what you want. Could you have a look and tell me what's wrong with it? -- https://jsfiddle.net/2njh1963/

Comment: Well, i want these to stick to their places. iphone - tablet or computer screen. What i have done now is made an @media for like 5 different widths. I thought that if i used like % of screen it should work on all the possible screen sizes. But it doesn't. (When I mean phone-sizes I mean they are in horizontal mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the following CSS and Found that none of your link is perfectly centered! here is the code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box.two {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 64);
  top: 0;
}

a {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

The image is the outcome of my code which you see. So I'm rewriting the code for you.
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navs {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.navtop {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.navright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.navbottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}


/* below code is for checking every thing is perfectly centered*/

.box {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box.two {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 64);
  top: 0;
}

a {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p id="navOne" class="navs navtop"><a href="about.html">About me</a></p>
<p id="navTwo" class="navs navright"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></p>
<p id="navThree" class="navs navbottom"><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></p>
<p id="navFour" class="navs navleft"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></p>

<!-- below html is for testing purpose -->
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box two "></div>
```

Comment: Omg, have you seriously fixed it for me? I'm gonna try to implement it and see. Thanks so much!

Comment: If it really work I owe you an up-vote! :), By the way It's a helpful community, everyone is really eager to help each other.

Comment: Yes it works perfect, and it works perfect on tilted mobile devices also! Much appreciated! Yes, this community seem very helpful. Good lads here :)

Comment: So you can now cheer my effort with accepting the answer or up-vote my answer. This is the way to appreciate an answer, not by commenting ! ;). Thanks for your comment too!